# Share large data between processes within a class

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to share a large numpy array between processes using pool.imap_unordered. Should be easy but I'm trying to do it from within a *class*. Right now I'm just passing the data everytime and everything works well until the data gets sufficiently large and pool just hangs and doesn't launch the parallel processes. Since only a subset of the large data is needed for each parallel process, an alternative is to only pass a subset, but I don't know how to in my current framework.

Since functions used for multiprocessing must be in the global namespace, I'm placing my function outside of the class as follows (toy example of real problem):

```
import numpy as np
import mutliprocessing.Pool
import itertools

def process(args):
    large_data, index = args
    return some_costly_operation(large_data[index])

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Let's pretend this is large
        self.data = np.zeros(10)

    def do(self):
        p = Pool()
        for result in p.imap_unordered(process,
            itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(self.data), xrange(10)))):

            print result
```

I know this is a hack-y way to do multiprocessing and theoretically you shouldn't do it from within a class and should protect by checking if you're in main... Any alternatives or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use binary/compact memory layout and `mmap` specifically for `numpy` arrays.

Code left as exercise to the reader, but I might try to hack something up :)

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I think a slight improvement is to use numpy.memmap specifically rather than python's mmap.

Comment: oh numpy provides it now? awesome! (I thought it had to be hacked using buffers)

Answer (score 1):

Can you serialize the data to disk from the caller, and just pass the filename to the worker process? If the response can be large the worker could serialize it and return the filename to caller. This is what I have used when I was working with large data sets.

Comment: Thanks, that would totally work. I'm hoping there's a less "hacky" however. Overall a bit disappointed w/ how multiprocessing interfaces with classes

Comment: I thought this over again and I'm not sure that would work because every instance has to load the data at some point anyways - leading to a RAM overload. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Multiprocessing lets you use shared memory, which seems like the only possible solution if you have to have multiple processes accessing same large memory structure at the same time. But this seems like a strange requirement. You could have caller serialize to disk, unload from memory, have worker load from disk, do the work and write to disk, unload from memory, etc. This way only one copy of any given data set will be in memory at any time.